# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> not binding to enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I'm trying to use `enum` as source of text and value for `DropDownList`. Unfortunately it's not working as expected - DropDownList has been populated but no options selected.
Here is enums:

```
public enum OrderLineState
        {
            Draft = 0,
            InProcess = 1,
            Done = 2
        }
```

Here is how I populate DropDown from enums:

```
    public IEnumerable<Helper.OrderLineStateData> GetOrderLineStates()
        {
            return from Enums.OrderLineState s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enums.OrderLineState))
                   select new Helper.OrderLineStateData() { OrderLineStateId = (int)s, OrderLineStateName = s.ToString() };
        }
```

This is Controller:

```
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EditOrderLine(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.OrderLineStates = new SelectList(_olr.GetOrderLineStates(), "OrderLineStateId", "OrderLineStateName");
            var result = await _olr.GetAllOrderLines(id);
            return PartialView(result);
        }
```

And finally - Razor View:

```
<td>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.LineState, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OrderLineStates, new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>
```

Comment: If you're open to a simple approach for population of the combobox, see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1055816/How-to-Add-the-Contents-of-a-Generic-List-of-Strin

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want to have hardcoded strings right in code of my solution.

Comment: Aren't they hardcoded if they are in an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are MVC 5 there is an enum helper. Try this:

```
public enum OrderLineState
{
    [Display(Name = "Draft")]
    Draft = 0,
    [Display(Name = "In Process")]
    InProcess = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Done")]
    Done = 2
}
```

Then

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.LineState)
```

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/aspnet-mvc-51/240168353

Comment: That's nice solutions but seemed like Linq to Entities not supporting cast from int to enum, something like this for example LineState = (Enums.OrderLineState)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Enums.OrderLineState) , x.State),